# Reversed table index in MySQL isn't detected

Tags: mysql

I've been persistently trying to speed up a MySQL query that involves an ORDER BY on a complex query. I've exhausted several options, and have gotten pretty close -- I've found the best solution to be implementing a pseudo-reverse index on the table in question.

I basically emulated the advice on this post (including variations using the id instead of publish date, using a joint index, etc):
http://www.igvita.com/2007/08/20/pseudo-reverse-indexes-in-mysql/

and successfully added the extra column, populated it, added an index, but the query

```
SELECT * FROM products USE INDEX (index_reverse_created);
```

doesn't seem to work. Inserting a random word or a regular column in place of the index name throws an error, so I realize it successfully detects the index.

Further inspection, using EXPLAIN SELECT *..., however, shows this:

http://i44.tinypic.com/2aes304.png

The peculiar part is (NULL) for both `possible_keys` and `key`.

SHOW INDEX FROM products yields this:

http://i41.tinypic.com/fvvdl1.png

And that seems like a healthy set of indices.

And altogether, I'm stumped. Seems like the index is there, but something goes wrong when trying to actually use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index will be used when there is where, order by, group by clauses in your query.
You wrote plain, simple query without any additional query and mysql will use fullscan and read data consequently.

Comment: I was about to facedesk after reading this, but even with a where and a group by clause, the reversed index doesn't seem to be working.

The query I used:
    SELECT id, user_id FROM products
    USE INDEX (index_reverse_created)
    WHERE id < 10000
    GROUP BY user_id;

Comment: And what is structure of your reversed index?

Comment: What exactly do you by structure? It is created by the following code: ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX index_reverse_created(reverse_created); The `reverse_created` is a column filled with timestampdiffs() of `created`.

Comment: It won't work in this case because at first you use group by and mysql doesn't guarantee what data will be field reverse_created for each rows and secondly you create index from 3 columns (id, user_id, reverse_created) and use ORDER BY reverse_created when you use group by clause mysql adds order by grouped columns implicitly.

Comment: OK, I guess I should stop generating hypothetical queries to find out why it would not work. In reality: I have a simple `SELECT` with a `JOIN` statement and the `WHERE` clause is `(a and b) or c`. Should `USE INDEX(...)` work with a setup like this?